# Writing objects serialized with Avro to HDFS using RollingSink in Flink [Scala]

Tags: scala, hadoop, avro, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to write case classes serialized to AVRO to HDFS using RollingSink in Flink. In order to make avro files deserializable by HDFS I use DataFileWriter which wraps FSDataOutputStream. When I try to synchronize between DataFileWriter and FSDataOutputStream in order to close the data file on HDFS the exception is thrown and I actually get data in every other file. Is there a way to sychronize fs stream with Avro writer in Flink Writer implementation?

I have tried using DataFileWriter close() flush() sync() fsync() but all failed. Sync method seems to perform best. I have also tried syncing in write method, which seemed to work, but still produced an error and I could not verify if all data is saved to files.

```
class AvroWriter[OutputContainer <: org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase] extends Writer[OutputContainer] {

  val serialVersionUID = 1L

  var outputStream: FSDataOutputStream = null
  var outputWriter: DataFileWriter[OutputContainer] = null

  override def open(outStream: FSDataOutputStream): Unit = {
    if (outputStream != null) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("AvroWriter has already been opened.")
    }
    outputStream = outStream

    if(outputWriter == null) {
      val writer: DatumWriter[OutputContainer] = new SpecificDatumWriter[OutputContainer](OutputContainer.SCHEMA$)
      outputWriter = new DataFileWriter[OutputContainer](writer)
      outputWriter.create(OutputContainer.SCHEMA$, outStream)
    }
  }

  override def flush(): Unit = {}

  override def close(): Unit = {
    if(outputWriter != null) {
      outputWriter.sync()
    }
    outputStream = null
  }

  override def write(element: OutputContainer) = {
    if (outputStream == null) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("AvroWriter has not been opened.")
    }
    outputWriter.append(element)
  }

  override def duplicate(): AvroWriter[OutputContainer] = {
    new AvroWriter[OutputContainer]
  }
}
```

Trying to run RollingSink with the above code gives following exception:

```
java.lang.Exception: Could not forward element to next operator
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.LegacyFetcher.run(LegacyFetcher.java:222)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer08.run(FlinkKafkaConsumer08.java:316)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:78)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask.run(SourceStreamTask.java:56)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:224)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:559)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not forward element to next operator
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:354)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:337)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource$NonTimestampContext.collect(StreamSource.java:158)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.LegacyFetcher$SimpleConsumerThread.run(LegacyFetcher.java:664)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.checkClosed(DFSOutputStream.java:1353)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSOutputSummer.write(FSOutputSummer.java:98)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.write(FSDataOutputStream.java:58)
        at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
        at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter$BufferedFileOutputStream$PositionFilter.write(DataFileWriter.java:446)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:121)
        at org.apache.avro.io.BufferedBinaryEncoder$OutputStreamSink.innerWrite(BufferedBinaryEncoder.java:216)
        at org.apache.avro.io.BufferedBinaryEncoder.writeFixed(BufferedBinaryEncoder.java:150)
        at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream$DataBlock.writeBlockTo(DataFileStream.java:366)
        at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.writeBlock(DataFileWriter.java:383)
        at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.sync(DataFileWriter.java:401)
        at pl.neptis.FlinkKafkaConsumer.utils.AvroWriter.close(AvroWriter.scala:36)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.fs.RollingSink.closeCurrentPartFile(RollingSink.java:476)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.fs.RollingSink.openNewPartFile(RollingSink.java:419)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.fs.RollingSink.invoke(RollingSink.java:373)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSink.processElement(StreamSink.java:39)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:351)
        ... 3 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found a solution. Because the stream is managed by RollingSink it cannot be closed in a class implementing Writer. On the other hand, if DataFileWriter wraps a stream and a file should be dumped to hdfs some sync or close is required. The trick is not to close DataFileWriter but sync it and then just discard it by assigning null to it (not very idiomatic way when you take into consideration Scala and functional programming, but hey, Flink is developed in Java). So this simple trick solved my problem:

```
override def close(): Unit = {
    if(outputWriter != null) {
      outputWriter.sync()
    }
    outputWriter = null
    outputStream = null
  }
```